# What is the most expensive item from Dota and Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I was wondering, what is the most expensive combined item from Dota and Dota 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dota 2:** Dagon Level 5

> Dagon upgraded to level 5 is the most expensive item in the game.

Source [Dota 2 Wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dagon)

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is answered but you got me curious so I made a list of the dota items ordered by price: (dagons and diffusal blade level 2 not included)

- Abyssal Blade - 6750
- Divine Rapier - 6200
- Satanic - 6150
- Butterfly - 6000
- Scythe of Vyse - 5675
- Eye of Skadi - 5675
- Daedalus - 5550
- Heart of Tarrasque - 5500
- Monkey King Bar - 5400
- Mjollnir - 5400
- Assault Cuirass - 5350
- Refresher Orb - 5300
- Linken's Sphere - 5175
- Radiance - 5150
- Manta Style - 5050
- Bloodstone - 5050
- Ethereal Blade - 4900
- Shiva's Guard - 4700
- Battle Fury - 4350
- Aghanim's Scepter - 4200
- Orchid Malevolence - 4125
- Sange and Yasha - 4100
- Desolator - 4100
- Black King Bar - 3900
- Heaven's Halberd - 3850
- Sacred Relic - 3800
- Pipe of Insight - 3628
- Soul Booster - 3300
- Diffusal Blade - 3300
- Eaglesong - 3300
- Reaver - 3200
- Rod of Atos - 3100
- Shadow Blade - 3000
- Skull Basher - 2950
- Dagon - 2720
- Eul's Scepter of Divinity - 2700
- Necronomicon - 2700
- Maelstrom - 2700
- Mystic Staff - 2700
- Veil of Discord - 2650
- Armlet of Mordiggian - 2600
- Boots of Travel - 2450
- Demon Edge - 2400
- Mekansm - 2306
- Force Staff - 2250
- Vanguard - 2225
- Blade Mail - 2200
- Blink Dagger - 2150
- Crystalys - 2150
- Hood of Defiance - 2125
- Ultimate Orb - 2100
- Hyperstone - 2100
- Vladmir's Offering - 2050
- Sange - 2050
- Yasha - 2050
- Hand of Midas - 1900
- Mask of Madness - 1900
- Helm of the Dominator - 1850
- Talisman of Evasion - 1800
- Drum of Endurance - 1775
- Perseverance - 1750
- Oblivion Staff - 1675
- Mithril Hammer - 1600
- Ghost Scepter - 1600
- Shadow Amulet - 1600
- Javelin - 1500
- Arcane Boots - 1450
- Platemail - 1400
- Claymore - 1400
- Power Treads - 1400
- Phase Boots - 1350
- Broadsword - 1200
- Point Booster - 1200
- Vitality Booster - 1100
- Medallion of Courage - 1075
- Ogre Club - 1000
- Blade of Alacrity - 1000
- Staff of Wizardry - 1000
- Energy Booster - 1000
- Ring of Aquila - 985
- Tranquil Boots - 975
- Helm of Iron Will - 950
- Quarterstaff - 900
- Morbid Mask - 900
- Urn of Shadows - 875
- Ring of Health - 875
- Void Stone - 875
- Gem of True Sight - 850
- Buckler - 803
- Soul Ring - 800
- Headdress - 603
- Bottle - 600
- Chainmail - 550
- Cloak - 550
- Poor Man's Shield - 550
- Bracer - 525
- Magic Wand - 509
- Gloves of Haste - 500
- Ring of Basilius - 500
- Wraith Band - 485
- Null Talisman - 470
- Belt of Strength - 450
- Band of Elvenskin - 450
- Robe of the Magi - 450
- Blades of Attack - 450
- Boots of Speed - 450
- Flying Courier - 370
- Ring of Regen - 350
- Sage's Mask - 325
- Orb of Venom - 275
- Stout Shield - 250
- Quelling Blade - 225
- Sentry Ward - 200
- Magic Stick - 200
- Circlet - 185
- Dust of Appearance - 180
- Ring of Protection - 175
- Animal Courier - 150
- Observer Ward - 150
- Gauntlets of Strength - 150
- Slippers of Agility - 150
- Mantle of Intelligence - 150
- Town Portal Scroll - 135
- Healing Salve - 100
- Smoke of Deceit - 100
- Tango - 90
- Iron Branch - 53
- Clarity - 50

Comment: You should include dagon and diffusal blade so that this might be the accepted answer.